# Pig - Join doesn't work

Tags: join, hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I have a problem with a join in pig. I'll begin by giving you the context. Here is my code:

```
-- START file loading
start_file = LOAD 'dir/start_file.csv' USING PigStorage(';') as (PARTRANGE:chararray,     COD_IPUSER:chararray);

-- trim
A = FOREACH start_file GENERATE TRIM(PARTRANGE) AS PARTRANGE, TRIM(COD_IPUSER) AS COD_IPUSER;

dump A;
```

which gives the output:

```
(79.92.147.88,20140310)
(79.92.147.88,20140310)
(109.31.67.3,20140310)
(109.31.67.3,20140310)
(109.7.229.143,20140310)
(109.8.114.133,20140310)
(77.198.79.99,20140310)
(77.200.174.171,20140310)
(77.200.174.171,20140310)
(109.17.117.212,20140310)
```

loading the other file:

```
-- Chargement du fichier recherche Hadopi
file2 = LOAD 'dir/file2.csv' USING PigStorage(';') as (IP_RECHERCHEE:chararray, DATE_HADO:chararray);

dump file2;
```

the output is this:

```
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,79.92.147.88)
(2014/03/10 00:00:01,79.92.147.88)
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,192.168.2.67)
```

Now, I want to do a left outer join. Here's the code:

```
result = JOIN file2 by IP_RECHERCHEE LEFT OUTER, A by COD_IPUSER;
dump result;
```

The output is this:

```
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,79.92.147.88,,)
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,192.168.2.67,,)
(2014/03/10 00:00:01,79.92.147.88,,)
```

All the records of "file2" are here, which is fine but any of start_file are here. It is like if the join has failed.

Do you know where the problem is ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have mislabeled your fields in `file2`. You are calling the first field the IP and the second field the date, when, as shown by your `dump`, the opposite is the case.  Try `FOREACH file2 GENERATE IP_RECHERCHEE` and you will see the fields you are trying to join on.

Answer (score 1):

The result is as expected. You are calling Left outer join , which looks for matching of IP_RECHERCHEE field in file2 with COD_IPUSER of A. 
**Since there is no matching, it returns all the IP_RECHERCHEE fields in file2 and puts null in place of fields from A.**

Clearly `2014/03/10 00:00:00 != 20140310`

Answer (score 1):

Your fields' name are wrong, and you join by the wrong field. It seems that you want to join by the IP address.

```
start_file = LOAD 'dir/start_file.csv' USING PigStorage(';') as (IP:chararray, PARTRANGE:chararray);

A = FOREACH start_file GENERATE TRIM(IP) AS IP, TRIM(PARTRANGE) AS PARTRANGE;

file2 = LOAD 'dir/file2.csv' USING PigStorage(';') as (DATE_HADO:chararray, IP:chararray);
```

what I got is this

```
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,192.168.2.67,,)
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,20140310)
(2014/03/10 00:00:00,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,20140310)
(2014/03/10 00:00:01,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,20140310)
(2014/03/10 00:00:01,79.92.147.88,79.92.147.88,20140310)
```